# Why is HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables not working

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to get the public IP address of the client using asp.net (mvc4) app. when I use
`HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` if gives me an empty string, and when I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` it send a string like this "::1" (without double quotes).
is it related to IIS express ??? how can i get the client IP using asp.net ??

Comment: You're running both client and server on the same machine, and not going via a proxy. No proxy == No HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR. Same machine, `::1` is the loopback address (a.k.a `localhost`)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the method I use to get the IP address:

```
    private static string GetIPAddress()
    {
        try
        {
            if (System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current != null)
            {
                var endpoint = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
                return endpoint.Address;
            }
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                // Check proxied IP address
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
                    return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] + " via " +
                        HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
                else
                    return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

            }
        }
        catch { }
        return "Unknown";
    }
```

Note that the first section is for WCF services since this code is from my logging code that's shared from both WCF and web projects, so you might just need the second section. You won't get an IP if you're hitting your localhost during development -- you'll get "::1" as you noticed. But you will get it if deployed on a server.

Comment: thanks mate, my code is pretty similar to the second part of your code. i will deploy it and see.

Comment: im also wondering if there is any server that can give me the client ip address, by making an ajax call to it ?